# Trying to figure out which view to edit!

Tags: views, 6

I have a main page of my site that has views and blocks. There is a photo view which I'm trying to figure out which one it is (drupal 6). I need to edit that view to change the sort order.

However (in admin mode) when I hover the cursor over the block of photos, the "Edit View" comes up and then when I move the cursor a bit upwards to edit it, the link disappears! So it's driving me mad which view to edit.

I have then gone to "site building"/ views / list and then I've changed the sort order of every view that has been named by that title but still the sort order on the main page doesn't change (i want to add sticky sort order).

So can anyone help by letting me know how to catch the edit view link that disappears when I hover the cursor around it? Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget to flush the cache!

Answer (score 1):

You can perhaps figure out what View it is from the id and class names on the containing markup which should tell you the view and the view display to edit. You can also change the theme to a core theme like Garland to get around whatever CSS issue you're having to get into the edit mode so you can identify the view.

Comment: You mean I should read the HTML source code?

Comment: Yes. The markup containing the view will have many classes on it which should help narrow it down.